# Text covered by image

Tags: lua, coronasdk

This code is used to generate balloons and texts but for some reason the texts are covered by the balloon. Is there a way to show the text on top of the image?

```
function scene:createScene(event)
 local group = self.view
local balloonText1 = display.newText('\227\129\130', 495, 125)
         local balloonText2 = display.newText('\227\129\132', 495, 175)
         local balloonText3 = display.newText('\227\129\134', 495, 225)
         local balloon = display.newImage ('balloon_fat_red.png', 495, 125)
               balloon = display.newImage ('balloon_fat_red.png', 495, 175)
               balloon = display.newImage ('balloon_fat_red.png', 495, 225)

         balloonText1:setFillColor( 1,1, 0 )
         balloonText2:setFillColor( 1,1, 0 )
         balloonText3:setFillColor( 1,1, 0 )
         balloon.name = 'balloon'
         physics.addBody(balloon)
         balloon.bodyType = 'static'

         group:insert(balloon)
         group:insert(balloonText1)
         group:insert(balloonText2)
         group:insert(balloonText3)

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Display objects that are displayed in the order they are in group, from back to front. So balloon will be blocked by text 1 which will be blocked by text 2 which will be blocked by text 3. You may have to spread out your text items and balloons (bigger gaps between y values).

The sections *Display Hierarchy* and *Moving Objects Forward and Backward* of [Working with Display Objects and the Stage](http://developer.coronalabs.com/content/application-programming-guide-graphics-and-drawing) provide useful information.

Also, at first I thought it was formatting issue but the following is surely problematic:

```
     local balloon = display.newImage ('balloon_fat_red.png', 495, 125)
           balloon = display.newImage ('balloon_fat_red.png', 495, 175)
           balloon = display.newImage ('balloon_fat_red.png', 495, 225)
```

This creates 3 balloons, putting them in the default stage. But only the last one created gets added to the scene group. Try

```
     local balloon = display.newImage ('balloon_fat_red.png', 495, 125)
     group:insert(balloon)
     balloon = display.newImage ('balloon_fat_red.png', 495, 175)
     group:insert(balloon)
     balloon = display.newImage ('balloon_fat_red.png', 495, 225)
     group:insert(balloon)
```

Comment: yes, as explained, if not enough gap between the y positions, you will get that, see update.

Comment: it doesn't seem be the case for the first 2 texts, i see that they are under the balloon image as I move them around adjusting the y value. The last thing that get added to the group is the top item which is why the 3rd text works. I tried using group:insert(1,balloon) to move the balloons to the bottom but doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the object:toFront()method to display object at front.
Here is the reference:
https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/type/DisplayObject/toFront.html